# Create backup/snapshot of table1 with timestamp in name, then select * from table1 into table1.YYYYMMDDHHMM.backup

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, mysql-workbench, backup

I have a table1 that has data uploaded to it every day.  The source can be unreliable in format and structure, so to avoid headaches and downtime, I want to take a snapshot of table1 every day before the upload runs.
I want to name the backups table1.YYYYMMDDHHMM.backup.  Straight up variables weren't working so I tried to use a prepare statement (which is completely new to me).  Below is what does not work... Some sage advice would be appreciated.

```
set @a = concat('CREATE TABLE `ops_weekly_sla.',@yyyymmdd,'.backup` like `ops_weekly_sla`;');

set @b = concat('SELECT * from `ops_sla_weekly` INTO `ops_weekly_sla.',@yyyymmdd,'.backup`;');

PREPARE stmt from @a;
EXECUTE stmt;

PREPARE stmt from @b;
EXECUTE stmt;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this a little differently.  Essentially instead of worrying about naming the backup table to start, I just rename it after it successfully is populated with the data snapshot.

```
create table backup like ops_weekly_sla;

INSERT INTO backup
select * from ops_weekly_sla;

SET @yyyymmdd = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m%d%H%i');
SET @a = concat('RENAME TABLE `backup` to `ops_weekly_sla.',@yyyymmdd,'.backup`;');

PREPARE stmt from @a;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Not only did this achieve my goal, bonus feature was that it did not disturb my timestamps for original data insertion or row updates.  /wewt!